# Good Money Habits and Principles

Tags: wealth-preservation

I want to know good money Habits that are universal and permanent.

Where can I learn about them?

Please help me with some sources.

Comment: I recommend reading money.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Learn by doing and learn by reading.

My personal favorites (which I have read no less than 3 times each)

- The Richest Man In Babylon **MUST READ**
- Rich Dad Poor Dad (First edition, not all the remakes) **MUST READ**
- The Millionaire Next Door **MUST READ**
- Think Big and Kick Ass (Donald Trump)
- Get Rich Stay Rich Pass It On
- Real Money (Jim Cramer)

You read these books you'll have a great pattern to building good wealth habits.